# How to pause a few seconds

Tags: android

I want to display images like a slideshow but I can't make it pause for 5 seconds before displaying the next image...

I have tried to make the thread sleep but it paused for 15 seconds and displayed the last (3rd) image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    File imgFile = new File(paths[i]);

    if(imgFile.exists()){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mimage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

    //**I want the thread pause for 5 seconds here**
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a handler

```
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                File imgFile = new  File(paths[i]);

                if(imgFile.exists())
                {

                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    mimage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            }
        }, 5000 * i );
    }
```

Comment: it still only display the latest image after pause

Comment: @Harish rightly edited my code's last line with `5000 * i` - did you include this in your test?

Comment: @Smittey Ah! No I did not. The first thing I noted in your answer was the delay duration in your handler where I felt something wrong in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class YourClass {
    private String[] paths;
    private int mNextImageIndex = 0;

    public void switch() {


        File imgFile = new  File(paths[mNextImageIndex]);

        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            mimage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

        mNextImageIndex = (mNextImageIndex + 1) % paths.length;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                switch();
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```