# putting a pause in code to show image after image?

Tags: java, android

I am a complete beginner in android. I am stuck at a point in making an application. I have images stored in hashmap and whatever line I give it as an input is broken into separate words on basis of space and its corresponding images are fetched. But I dont want these images to show up at once but these should be shown one after the other and there should be a pause of almost one second between each image to show up. But seems like I am stuck because of my inexperience. In code where and how should I place a pause? Because when I use `Thread.sleep` anywhere in code, it pause only in beginning everytime.

```
textlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


                Speech.setText("You said " + matches_text.get(position));
                selectedFromList = (matches_text.get(position));

                 String[] separated = selectedFromList.split(" ");
                // ImageView iv;
                final int[] imageViews = { R.id.imageView1,
                        R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView3, R.id.imageView4,
                        R.id.imageView5, R.id.imageView6, R.id.imageView7,
                        R.id.imageView8, R.id.imageView9, R.id.imageView10,
                        R.id.imageView11, R.id.imageView12,
                        R.id.imageView13, R.id.imageView14,
                        R.id.imageView15, R.id.imageView16,

                };  

                final_length = separated.length;
                int b = 0;

                HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();              
                map.put("apple",R.drawable.apple);



                maps pol=new maps();
                pol.map_A();
                pol.map_B();
                pol.map_C();
                pol.map_D();
                pol.map_E();


                for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++) {

                    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViews[i]);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            100, 100);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            if(pol.map_a.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_a.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_b.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                        iv.setImageResource(pol.map_b.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                                     }
            else if(pol.map_c.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_c.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_d.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_d.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
            else if(pol.map_e.containsKey(separated[i].toLowerCase())){

                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_e.get(separated[i].toLowerCase()));
                             }
}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pause a few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812806/how-to-pause-a-few-seconds)

Comment: Try Thread.sleep(1000);?

Comment: @Dev do not recommend or use Thread.sleep() unless you are working on non UI thread. Using Thread.sleep() on UI thread will interrupt user actions on your app and it will eventually end up in ANR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop as following:

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();

for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++) {
    final int iDupe = i;
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViews[iDupe]);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
            iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            if(pol.map_a.containsKey(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase())) {
                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_a.get(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase()));
            }
            else if(pol.map_b.containsKey(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase())) {
                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_b.get(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase()));
            }
            else if(pol.map_c.containsKey(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase())) {
                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_c.get(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase()));
            }
            else if(pol.map_d.containsKey(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase())) {
                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_d.get(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase()));
            }
            else if(pol.map_e.containsKey(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase())) {
                iv.setImageResource(pol.map_e.get(separated[iDupe].toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if worked. This will prevent more people spending time on this question. Thanks